# Multiple cookies with javascript, stategies anyone?

Tags: javascript, cookies

LocalStorage doesn't work here. I am looking for more of a theory type answer and not as much code. I already know how to set and delete cookies, that is now what this question is about; here is the question:

When I submit an order, I want to place

```
Meal
Ingredients
Name
Phone
```

inside cookies to be later outputted on a div to the right of the page. This I think I can do quite easily. I might put each value into an object of orders...

But that isn't the real question, how can I have multiple orders that are unique? I want to have many different orders and have the user delete the order they desire. I was thinking of separating each order with a | character and than playing some string games. But I don't know how I would delete one.

My other idea was have a order id and auto-increment it. Any help? website: [philipimperato.com/mobileOrder](http://philipimperato.com/mobileOrder)

P.S. Only Javascript and I know how to setCookie and deleteCookie :D

Answer (score 1):

Cookies don't seem the place do to this anymore. Cookies are limited and are sent with each HTTP request, including all of your images and static files unless they are on a different domain. I recommend using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage) instead. Since this is intended for smartphones like the iPhone and Android you are ok to use localStorage. Webkit browsers have supported it for a long time. If you use localStorage you can use any kind of key value storage mechanism you like. I recommend the redis way of field:id:property for keys.

```
var order_id = 10203;
var key = 'order:' + order_id + ':drink';
localStorage[key] = 'Pepsi';
```

By using the order_id in your key field you can easily manage unique orders.

Comment: also he could use a framework that **simulates** localStorage on older browsers. http://r2bew.tk/something-like-this

Comment: ... or a database (MS SQL, mySQL, etc.)

Comment: The issues is that this must work in IE 7 and IE 8 which doesn't support (I don't think) that type of technology

Comment: as ZJR said, a library or framework can help you simulate it for legacy browsers: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills

Comment: In which case I recommend setting a session cookie and storing this information on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You could *serialize* an order object array in ***json*** and parse it back as you load

(This could present **security issues**, and maybe you should use a framework to parse json back to life. Many frameworks do some lint on json before `eval`uating it, some even *parse it all by themselves*)